# How to use ffmpeg to add picture watermark and text watermark at the same time

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

ffmpeg -y -i test.mp4 -i bkg.png -filter_complex "[0:v]drawtext=fontfile=PingFang-SC-Regular.ttf:text='check.....':fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:x=200:y=200:enable='if(gt(t,10),lt(t,20))'[text];[text][1:v]overlay=x=180:y=180:enable='if(gt(t,9.9),lt(t,20))'[out]" -map "[out]" out.mp4

How to put the picture watermark in the front?I'm going to put the text on the picture

Comment: i have lots of watermark and text watermark to insert

Comment: You're overlaying just the text on the watermark — you have to overlay that onto the first input video as well. If you have lots of elements, you have to programmatically construct the command.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but if the watermark is in front of the watermark, it will cause errors.

Comment: like this :   ffmpeg -y -i test.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v]overlay=200:200[p1];[p1][1:v]drawtext=fontfile=PingFang-SC-Regular.ttf:text='hellow':fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:x=200:y=200:enable='if(gt(t,10),lt(t,20))'[out]" -map "[out]" out.mp4   (it was error: Too many inputs specified for the "drawtext" filter)

Comment: You have specified multiple inputs for the drawtext filter, as the error says. It only takes one. Also your overlay command has only one input; it should have two.

Comment: But why the subtitle file is in front was success

Comment: In the example you've shown in your question, you are drawing subtitles on top of your input video, then outputting to `text`. Then you overlay `1:v` on top of `text`. Your other example is not logical. You should overlay the watermark first (the overlay filter takes two inputs), then draw the text on that.